# I found a syntax error making a list I can't fix

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, append, syntax-error

When I am trying to do:

```
d10.append(i if (float(d06[1])/float(datalist05[13]) > 0.02))
```

It returns:

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

And points to the last parenthesis. I have already checked most things (the line before it has its correct parenthesis, the lists are correctly indexed, it is inside a `for` loop, that's why the `i` is there, but the `.append()` function was working right before this...) I don't really know what else to try.

Comment: why dont you just make life easier and do X = i if... and d10.append(X)?

Comment: The conditional expression requires an `else`; what would the argument to `append` be if the condition in your example were false?

Comment: If you only want to call `d10.append` when the condition is true, then use an `if` statement.

Comment: If you're trying to express "do this thing or don't", use an `if` statement, not a conditional expression. Conditional expressions are for "use this value or this other value".

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't need to be a one liner right? Why not just set a conditional argument and append i to d10 if it's met.

```
if (float(d06[1])/float(datalist05[13]) > 0.02):
     d10.append(i)
```

Comment: `extend` could be used here with a generator expression, which *would* use syntax that looks like an else-less expression: `d10.extend(i for i in items if float(d06[1])/float(datalist05[13]) > 0.02)`

Comment: Given that the condition doesn't depend on `i`, though, an `if` statement would still be more appropriate, because you're either adding every element of `items` to `d10` or not.

Comment: Right, we can eliminate the example loop, just use the if statement.